# How to get the common ordered characters between 2 strings in python?

Tags: python

How to get the common ordered characters between 2 strings in python?

for example:

```
str1 = 'AAA'
str2 = 'AXA'
```

output should be `'AA'`

Comment: Do you want them to be at the same place or do you match ABC to AZB to find AB? For that matter does ABC match ACB as AB or AC?

Comment: yes I want them to be at the same place same indexing so in case of ABC AZB it should output only 'A'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare each characters from 2 strings and keep it when they are the same:

```
str1 = 'AAA'
str2 = 'AXA'

str3 = ''.join(c1 for c1, c2 in zip(str1, str2) if c1 == c2)
print(str3)

# Output
'AA'
```

Other example:

```
str1 = 'ABC'
str2 = 'AZB'

str3 = ''.join(c1 for c1, c2 in zip(str1, str2) if c1 == c2)
print(str3)

# Output
'A'
```

Comment: WOW it worked !! big thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
result = ''
for i in range(0, len(str1)):
    if str1[i] == str2[i]:
       result += str1[i]

print(result)
```